# Javafx cell not selecting when button is clicked

Tags: java, javafx

I have a custom cellFactory and a button in every cell. When any of the other nodes are clicked the row in the list is selected, but it doesn't select the row if the button is clicked.

My cellFactory:

```
public class OrderListViewCell extends ListCell<Order> {
    @FXML
    private Pane container;

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    private FXMLLoader mLLoader;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Order order, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(order, empty);

        if(empty || order == null) {

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

        } else {
            if (mLLoader == null) {
                mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/order-cell.fxml"));
                mLLoader.setController(this);
                try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(container);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on a control may not allow to select the list cell by default. You have to handle the selection manually in this case.
Include a clicked handler to button to select the underlying listcell. something like ...

```
    try {
          mLLoader.load();
          button.setOnMouseClicked(e -> getListView().getSelectionModel().select(getItem()));
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Remember that you will NOT get the :focused:selected selection style for listCell, as the button will have focus.